# how to make circles draw in a circle. Kind of complicated

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

so im working on a code that draws a spirograph, and whenever i run the code, it draws a spirograph. Normal, right? The only thing is that i want the spirograph to draw from the 4th quadrant to the third, the third to the second, and the second to the first. What happens is that the spirograph draws circles starting from the 4th quadrant, then the third, then goes to the middle of the 2nd and 1st quadrant and draws circles coming down like a fountain. You will see what i mean when you run the code. So what i want, is for the spirograph to draw in a circle formation-draw circles on the 4th quadrant, then third, then 2nd, then 1st. Done. Any help would be appreciated. This is the code:

```
import time

import pygame
import math
import sys

# setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
# setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
# how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
# the space between each circle
turnangle = 360 / 35
# width of screen
width = 600
# height of screen
height = 600
# radius of circles
radius = 100
# making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# if the code is running, then continue
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
alpha = turnangle
circles = []
# draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # second quarter of circles
        if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
            # last quarter of circles
        if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

        circles.append(([x, y], cl, alpha))
        alpha = alpha + turnangle
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)
        #circle = [pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)]
        #circles = {'circles': circle.get_rect()}

# move"
trangleedge = radius
movetimes = 1
time.sleep(2)



# exit only when user clicks on exit button
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    while movetimes <= 100:
        trangleedge = trangleedge + 1
        for circle in circles:
            #x = circle[0][0]
            #y = circle[0][1]
            alpha = circle[2]
            cl = circle[1]

            if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # second quarter of circles
            if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                y = 300 + trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # third quarter of circles
            if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
                x = 300 - trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
                # last quarter of circles
            if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
                x = 300 + trangleedge * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                y = 300 - trangleedge * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
                #pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

            circle[0][0] = x
            circle[0][1] = y
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for center, color, alpha in circles:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radius, 2)

            pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
        movetimes += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have the axes swapped in the NW quadrant.  You need:

```
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
```

And, by the way, there's no need to check the lower bounds of the angle.  `angle` cannot be less than zero.  So you can replace the first loop with:

```
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        if alpha < 90:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
            # second quarter of circles
        elif alpha < 180:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            y = 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))
            # third quarter of circles
        elif alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha - 180))
            # last quarter of circles
        elif alpha < 360:
            x = 300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)

        circles.append(([x, y], cl, alpha))
        alpha += turnangle
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix it would be changing this section:

```
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
```

To this:

```
            # third quarter of circles
        if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
            x = 300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 + alpha))
            y = 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 + alpha))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, cl, (x, y), radius, width=2)
```

Now it draws the circles in a continuous circle and then continues.